# Issue with Ionic 'Pull To Refresh' and 'ion-scroll' on the same page [Video provided]

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Hopefully I'll get more luck here as using the Ionic Forum I didn't get much response. I'll provide a video to also show my issue so you can see what is happening.

Essentially I have a page which contains an ionic pull to refresh event, and also a small fixed height ion-scroll. Now, there is no issues with iOS however the bug is persistent on Android, and the only way to combat said bug is to use 2 fingers to scoll on the ion-scroll. I essentially want the Android to behavior the same as iOS. So when the user scrolls up and down the ion-scroll it does NOT activate the pull to refresh event whilst the touch is within the ion-scroll.

```html
<ion-view title="Sales Information">
  <ion-content id="container">
    <ion-refresher pulling-text="Pull to refresh..." on-refresh=PullToRefresh()>
    </ion-refresher>
    <ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)" style="margin-top: -15px;">
      <ion-slide>
        <div class="list card">
          <div id="beforeRAWData">
            <!-- Content -->
          </div>
          <ion-scroll style="max-height: {{ calcHeight }};" ng-if="deptSalesDate == '(Week)'">
            <!-- Content -->
          </ion-scroll>
          <ion-scroll style="max-height: {{ calcHeight }};" ng-if="deptSalesDate == '(Today)'">
            <!-- Content -->
          </ion-scroll>
        </div>
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slide-box>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Video showing iOS working, and Android failing:
https://youtu.be/uYmx5Ni5dgE

Hopefully the video helps you understand my issue.

Comment: Have you had any luck fixing this by any chance?

Comment: Unfortunately the project has been put on hold, and since it was a good 6 months ago I can't remember off the top of my head if I actually found or created a solution. If I find any spare time on my hands, I'll run a test against the project and see if it differs. And if I did resolve it, I'll update my original post with a fix for anyone in the future who may experience the same issue.

Comment: Having the same issue. Is there any solution now?

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Wee need this directive to prevent page refresh on grid view scrolling
 */
@Directive({
    selector: '[scrollCatcher]'
})
export class ScrollCatcherDirective {

    private scrollElement: HTMLElement;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.scrollElement = this.el.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName(
            'scroll-content',
        )[0];
        this.scrollElement.addEventListener(
            'touchstart',
            (event: TouchEvent) => {
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                event.cancelBubble = true;
            },
        );

        this.scrollElement.addEventListener('touchend', (event: TouchEvent) => {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            event.cancelBubble = true;
        });
    }
}
```

and in the .html file:

```
<ion-content scrollCatcher>
<ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
    <ion-refresher-content></ion-refresher-content>
  </ion-refresher>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: The question is about ionic 1, but you're talking about ionic 2+.